# EF Database not Connected Exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, exception, database-connection

I'm using Entity Framework with C# and I need to be able to check weather the database is connected and in case it isn't throw an Exception so the application doesn't crash.
Any ideas?
thank you!

Comment: Do you want to throw an exception so the application does **not** crash? Best way is to simply create DatabaseContext instance and try to query any record, EF will even throw an exception for you...

Answer (score 1):

A simple implementation would be something like this

```
private bool TestConnEF()
{
    using (var db = new DbContext())
    {
        try
        {
            db.Database.Connection.Open();
            if (db.Database.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the DB connection is valid:

```
DatabaseContext.Exists();
```

If a server machine is up, use [`Ping.Send`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7hzczzed.aspx) Method:

```
Ping.Send Method (String)
```